# How to disable /etc/xdg/{something}?

Tags: kde, xdg, kwin

Take `/etc/xdg/kwinrulesrc` for example:

```
$ cat /etc/xdg/kwinrulesrc
[1]
Description=dde-dock
desktop=-1
desktoprule=2
wmclass=dde-dock dde-dock
wmclasscomplete=true
wmclassmatch=1

[2]
Description=dde-launcher
strictgeometry=false
strictgeometryrule=2
wmclass=dde-launcher dde-launcher
wmclasscomplete=true
wmclassmatch=1
```

It will be launched automatically after startup. How to disable this script forever without deleting it?

Comment: Can you comment on the environment specification (such as linux distribution and version)? I am somewhat puzzled because normally, files that are to be autostarted reside under `/etc/xdg/autostart` and are `.desktop` files (as per [freedesktop.org-specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html)).

Comment: Commenting the whole content of the script is an option?

Comment: `chmod 000 <the file>` ; if one can't read it, one can't do anything with it :)

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Autostart, to disable a system-wide entry, you can create an overriding entry containing Hidden=true. I assume that adding Hidden=true to the main entry might work as well, but I did not try out.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** Create a `~/.config/autostart` directory.

**2.** Copy `/etc/autostart/entry` to `~/.config/autostart/entry`.

**3.** Add `Hidden=true` to `~/.config/autostart/entry`. E. g.

```
# ~/.config/autostart/picom.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=picom
GenericName=X Compositor
Icon=picom
Exec=picom
Hidden=true
```

4. Reboot the system. The desktop entry will be disabled and the program won't start.

**Details**

[XDG Autostart - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Autostart)

[autostart-spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/autostart-spec)

Comment: This worked for me, but also you don't have to copy the entire file: you just need to create a file with the same name that has the lines `[Desktop Entry]` and `Hidden=true` (though copying makes it easy to get the file name correctly).

Comment: For GNOME, you can also use `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false`